# IInternetProtocolRoot::Start is never called

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol Handler according to
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(v=vs.85).aspx#Creating_an_Asynchro
but step 3 is not happens. Urlmon.dll is supposed to call QueryInterface on my pluggable protocol handler for its IInternetProtocol interface and it does not. I am missing something and I can not figure it out. Does anybody know what the problem?

On step 2, `ParseUrl` is called twice:

```
if( ParseAction == PARSEACTION::PARSE_SECURITY_URL ) {
        if( cchResult < _countof(L"http://localhost/") ) {
            return S_FALSE;
        }
        memcpy(pwzResult, L"http://localhost/", sizeof(L"http://localhost/"));
        *pcchResult = _countof(L"http://localhost/") - 1;
        return S_OK;
    }

if( ParseAction == PARSEACTION::PARSE_DOMAIN ) {
        if( cchResult < _countof(L"localhost") ) {
            return S_FALSE;
        }
        memcpy(pwzResult, L"localhost", sizeof(L"localhost"));
        *pcchResult = _countof(L"localhost") - 1;
        return S_OK;
}
return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION;
```

Comment: Did you complete the 9 steps for creation, including registration? Have you rebooted, or at least logged off and back on? Are you returning the proper interfaces in steps 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, it is registered and Urlmon.dll calls IInternetProtocolInfo::ParseUrl.

Comment: I assume that you're returning `S_OK` from that call, and the correct string and length. What's being sent as the `PARSEACTION`? (Also a bit of the code you're using like the `QueryInterface` handler and the `ParseUrl` method, or better yet, a [mcve] would be really helpful for looking into this further)

Comment: `ParseUrl` is called twice:
1. `if( ParseAction == PARSEACTION::PARSE_SECURITY_URL ) {
  if( cchResult < _countof(L"http://localhost/") ) {
   return S_FALSE;
  }
  memcpy(pwzResult, L"http://localhost/", sizeof(L"http://localhost/"));
  *pcchResult = _countof(L"http://localhost/") - 1;
  return S_OK;
 }`
2. `if( ParseAction == PARSEACTION::PARSE_DOMAIN ) {
memcpy(pwzResult, L"localhost", sizeof(L"localhost"));
  *pcchResult = _countof(L"localhost") - 1;
  return S_OK; 
}`

Comment: Please [edit] the code into your question. :)